# Configure Java CV with eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, opencv, javacv

I am having a 64-bit windows 7 laptop.

I have opencv version 2.4.2. I have extracted it in the C:

I have eclipse juno classic on my laptop.

Jdk 7 64-bit version is installed and and path variable set so i can access javac from CMD.

I have javacv-0.2 downloaded from google projects.

for opencv i have added following path to the classpath variable.

C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)

I have inclused javacv.jar, javacpp.jar and javacv-windows-x86_64.jar in the ProjectBuildPath of eclipse.

Yet when i try to write following program function cvLoadImage(), cvSmooth(), cvSaveImage and cvReleaseImage() they are not identified and available to me.

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

public class ssss {
    public static void main(String filename) { 
    IplImage image = cvLoadImage(filename);
        if (image != null) {
            cvSmooth(image, image, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3);
            cvSaveImage(filename, image);
            cvReleaseImage(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me. If you need any other information regarding it do let know.

I followed the instruction available at this link to configure java-cv: http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/12/opencv-javacv-eclipse-project.html

Regards,
Priyank

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you are using 64bit system. But you have set path for 32bit binaries. correct path for 64 bit system should be

`C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\`

Comment: sorry that was a type from my end. Thanks for pointing it out. but in my system I have given path which you have mentioned.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by functions are not identified and available to you? Are you able to run program? If you are getting any specific error, please post.

Comment: What exactly i meant, when i type IplImage, eclipse intellisense identifies it and inserts it in the editor. but when i type cvLoadImage() or cvSmooth() eclipse doesn't show them in intellisense and also if i type them manually it shows them there is no such method.